# Concatenate first and last name with last name all in uppercase

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a mysql query that displays all first names concatenated with the last name in uppercase, with a space between first and last name.

What I've got atm:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", `First_Name`, `Last_Name`) AS Name from tblDetails
```

I'm new to mysql and I can't figure out where to put UPPER, doesn't seem to work anywhere.

Also I need to do the same as above but add a prefix of Mr or Ms depending on the gender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `case` and `concat` to add prefix based on gender and `upper` can be applied to both First_Name, Last_Name column values and then use `concat_ws` to append them with a space in between.

```
SELECT  CONCAT ( (case when gender ='M' 
                       then  'Mr '
                       else 'Ms '
                       end
                  ),
             CONCAT_WS(" ", UPPER(First_Name), UPPER(Last_Name)) 
               )
       AS Name 
from tblDetails
```

Comment: SELECT  CONCAT ( (case when gender ='Male' then  'Mr 'else 'Ms  'end),
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", First_Name, Last_Name)) AS Name FROM tblDetails;

Comment: The above is what I've got for adding the prefix and concatenating first and last name, don't need uppercase for this one.

Comment: @Faker, you have select concat_ws , you should have just concat_ws

Comment: You're a legend mate! Cheers :D